# How to work with custom Custom data-* attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The `data-*` attributes are used to store custom data. The `data-*` attributes generated through jQuery are not visible in the DOM while the `data-*` attributes written in the HTML code are visible in the DOM.

My question is what difference is making the jQuery generated element's `data-*` attributes not visible in the DOM?

Secondly, can we hide `data-*` in the DOM object like in the element generated through jQuery?

```js
$('#div2').append($('<h2/>').html('h2 Element generated with JQUERY').data('test', '5000'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <h2 data-test="60000">This is h2 Element</h2>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: 1) If you use `data()` to change the attribute value then jQuery stores the value in an in-memory object for better performance over calls to change/read the DOM. If you use `data()` as both getter and setter, you'll have no issues. See the duplicate for more information 2) Yes, use `dataset`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: "*Secondly, can we hide `data-*` in the DOM object like in the element generated through jQuery?*" - as in the duplicate and above, you're not "hiding" the `data-*`, it's just not being added in the first place.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your comment is making sense Thanks. But the title of question do not justify.

Comment: @ArifH-Shigri Glad it helped. I updated the title to remove the tags, as they don't go there.